# jQuery TopDistance animation start?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem with the script that I wrote.
Well, for some reason, it not refers to TopDistance which is declared to 850. Just one clicked on the down arrow and the animation starts.

Can you help with this early boot animation?

```
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('.projekt').each(function () {
            var topDistance = $(this).offset().top;

            if ((topDistance - 850) < scrollTop) {
                $(this).addClass("animated fadeInRight");
            }
        });
    });


        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('.projekt').each(function () {
            var topDistance = $(this).offset().top;

            if ((topDistance - 850) < scrollTop) {
                $(this).removeClass("projekt");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: A tip for debugging. Try `console.log(topDistance)` and put it before the `.addClass()` method.

Comment: both `.on('scroll)` functions are doing the same thing, without seeing more code my only guess is that you mean for the first `if ((topDistance - 850) < scrollTop)` to be something like `if ((topDistance - 850) <= scrollTop)`. without the `<=` you will never match `0`

Comment: I could ask for to improve my code according to your proposals?
Unfortunately, I do not sit too long in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArtyukhAlex/6tjnpzse/1/).
I've made one function instead of two and it works.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('.projekt').each(function () {
        var topDistance = $(this).offset().top;

        if ((topDistance - 850) < scrollTop) {
            $(this).addClass("animated fadeInRight").removeClass('projekt');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: We still do not work as expected. I wish PROJEKTOWANIE GRAFICZNE, KODOWANIE and APLIKACJE columns appeared when the hero image disappears - roughly in position 570. 

Already changed two functions for one, changed the value of TopDistance and continue without progress.

Below page on which you want to run the script:
www.damiansonek.eu/creative

Any ideas?